# Problem adding a trendline to a graph in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to use `geom_smooth(method = "lm")` and it doesn't work...

```
percentage.no.work <- cleanData %>% group_by(AREA) %>%
  summarise(percentage = mean(ESTIMATED.CITY.UNEMPLOYMENT))

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=percentage.no.work, aes(x=AREA, y=percentage), alpha=0.6, color="purple", size=2) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  theme_minimal() + ggtitle("Percentage Estimated City Unemployment") + 
  ylab("Percentage")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the aesthetics for the `geom_smooth` as well. Either by including it in the `ggplot()` or in the `geom_smooth()` :

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=percentage.no.work, aes(x=AREA, y=percentage), alpha=0.6, color="purple", size=2) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=AREA, y=percentage), method = "lm") +
  theme_minimal() + ggtitle("Percentage Estimated City Unemployment") + 
  ylab("Percentage")
```

You can avoid repeating section of the code putting it in the `ggplot()`

```r
ggplot(data=percentage.no.work, aes(x=AREA, y=percentage)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.6, color="purple", size=2) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  theme_minimal() + ggtitle("Percentage Estimated City Unemployment") + 
  ylab("Percentage")
```